# Mysql get Linked and not linked Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I amm trying to do a query  with a `if exist`  to get  the primary key which are linked and not linked to other tables. This is my query

```
SELECT *, IF( EXISTS(
             SELECT * FROM categorias
  Where (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM actividades where categorias.categoriaID)=0)  , "YES", "NO") 
  FROM  categorias
```

I get always `YES` even when few primary key are not linked.  Any help would be useful.

My table categories as the father table and the children table is  `actividades (FK from categorias)`

In my `categorias` tables I have 3 types

```
 CategoriaID   TYPE
   1           ADMIN
   2           USEER
   3           W/E
```

and in my children table I have

```
ChildrenID  FatherID(categoria)    NAME
1                 1                NONE
```

the results of the query should be

```
1 ADMIN NO
2 USEER YES
3 W/E  YEs
```

Since my if condition put `YES` if the father don't have a children ID.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution without 'IF'

```
SELECT t1.column_name, 'NO' AS column_name 
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.id = t2.t1_id
UNION
SELECT column_name, 'Yes' AS column_name 
FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT t1_id FROM table2);
```

### Solution with 'IF'

```
SELECT column_name, IF(id IN(SELECT t1_id FROM table2), 'NO', 'Yes') AS column_name
FROM table1;
```

I hope I was able to help you.